# How can I list all new processes as they are created?

Tags: logging, process, ps

I'm familiar with tools such as `ps` and `top`, but to my knowledge, they don't catch all new processes. `top` has a log mode, but if the process is short-lived enough (e.g. `echo 'Hello, World!'`, then the process won't be logged.

This being said, is there any way to just list all newly-created processes as they are created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is "process accounting".

If you are using Linux, then there is a package called **psacct** that you can install and start.

Answer (score 0):

If the /proc filesystem is available to you, then you IMHO could go through it searching for files named cmdline. I assume they will contain the original command lines as they were specified while starting each particular process.